# Can't access Superclass method on subclass object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, refactoring

I have problem with inheritance in Java - with accessing Superclass method on a subclass Object. I didn't find any solution on StackOverFlow, but there are multiple posts with the same title which don't help.

- Superclass (Person) where I defined a static method as follow:

  ```
  ...variables with getter methods

  //the constructor
  public Person(String fname, String lname, String code, String spec) {
          this.firstName = fname;
          this.lastName = lname;
          this.personalCode = code;
          this.profession = spec;
      }
  public static List<Person> getAll(String csvFile) {
      List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
  ```
- My Subclass (Programmers) extends Superclass (Person) and has a constructor using `super` keyword.

  ````
  public Programmers(String fname, String lname, String code, String spec){
      super(fname, lname, code, spec);
      }```
  ````
- I would like to call `getAll("mycsvFile")` method from the Subperclass in my `Main` class inside the `main` method.

  ```
  List<Programmers> programmers = Programmers.getAll("programmers.csv");
  ```

but I get error on this line where I can't access the `getAll()` method.

Comment: `static` methods aren't inherited. But you should be able to call a `public static` method from a superclass. `List<Person> programmers = Person.getAll("programmers.csv");` -- also, how are `Patient` and `Programmers` the same thing?

Comment: List<Person> Isn’t the same thing as List<Programmers>. I think you might be better of with using factories of some kind

Comment: which error? Probably a type mismatch and not "can't access"

Comment: @Elliott `static` methods **are** inherited according [JLS 8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8-100): "*A class C inherits from its direct superclass type D all concrete methods m (both static and instance) ...*"

Comment: Removed static and now I have the following error: 

`
Non-static method 'getAll(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context
`

Comment: Complete code is here: https://pastecode.io/s/t6i7mttu

Comment: You're trying to invoke the method as a static method still. You need to change `List<Programmers> programmers = Programmers.getAll("programmers.csv")` to call on one object.